# Finding characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

I need to find the characteristic polynomial $P_A$. And I know that $A^2+A+5I=0$, and $A$ is square matrix.

I don't know how to proceed. I think found that $A = -5(A+I)^{-1}$ but have no idea about the rest.

Update: $A$ is real and it is an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Are you familiar with the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)?

Comment: thank for responding, I know that P(A) should be equal to zero. but not sure how to use it here

Comment: @shazar123 Well, you have a polynomial in $A$. So, if $p(x)=x^2+x+5$, then what is $p(A)$?

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a real matrix, then $P$ is a power of $x^2+x+5$, because the latter is irreducible over the reals.

If $A$ is a complex matrix, then all you can say is that the irreducible factors of $P$ are among the factors of $x^2+x+5$.